# Unknown system variable 'sql_mode' error upon connecting to MySQL server 4.0.18 with mysql2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to connect to an external database from my Rails 4.2.3 app with mysql2 0.3.18, but I keep getting the following error in my view:

Unknown system variable 'sql_mode'

I'm guessing that the variable is being set when the connection is made, so I tried adding the followings to my connection settings in database.yml to prevent that:

strict: :default

strict: false

variables:
  sql_mode: ''

variables:
  sql_mode: :default

variables:
   strict_mode: false

Same error each time. Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

SQL_MODE variable is supported only from MySQL 4.1 version

Comment: I don't doubt that. My problem is that both the database version and the version of Rails are given factors (especially the former). As I've said, I'm trying to _get rid of_ the 'sql_mode' so I can connect.